# I am trying to create user defined function for string comaparision which takes input from user in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
`read -p "Enter first string: " VAR1`
`read  -p "Enter second string: " VAR2`

`echo "You entered $VAR1"`
`echo "You entered $VAR2"`

`function display()`
`{`
    `a=$1`
    `b=$2`

    if [ '$a' == '$b' ]; then
       echo "Strings are equal"
    else
       echo "Strings are not equal"
    fi

`}`

`display VAR1 VAR2`
```

Function is not giving desired output, it always returns "Strings are not equal"

Comment: `display VAR1 VAR2` compares literal string `VAR1` to literal string `VAR2`, which are not equal. If you want to compare contents of variables, you may want to prepend `$`: `display $VAR1 $VAR2`.

Comment: Please edit your question, so that each line of code is also shown in each one line in the question.

Answer (score 1):

- the [ takes = sign as comparison operator, not the ==. Please use =.
- the quoting '' does not allow the shell to resolve the $, please use "" quotes instead.